# Glass Shader with Boolean Difference operator?

Tags: modifiers, glass

I created a cube and a smaller sphere, used Boolean difference to cut the sphere away from the cube, then applied this modifier, and moved the sphere out of the way.

I use the Glass Shader on the cube, and added a background image, so I can see the refractino of the glass.

The cube refracts intuitively for all its faces, except the cut faces, using either Eevee or Cycles.

Why do the cut surfaces appear opaque, and not transparent? How to fix this?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit: after following Nathan and John Eason's advice, it is working :) Here is a picture where I assigned the same material to the cutting objects, then made two additional cuts, that are correctly transparent :) :

[image]

Comment: Are the normals correct on the 'cut' faces? - Select All in Edit mode and then Shift-N to recalculate them.

Comment: They probably got assigned a different material (they acquire material index from cutting surface.)  Check the material and reassign to refraction mat if necessary.

Comment: Yes indeed. I usually apply the same material to the cutter as the object being cut.

Comment: Great! that fixes it. Thank you :)